# TSQL-ORDER BY clause in a CTE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can we use `ORDER BY` clause in a CTE expression?

```
;with y as
(
     select 
         txn_Date_Time, txn_time, card_No, batch_No, terminal_ID
     from 
         C1_Transaction_Information
     where 
         txn_Date_Time = '2017-10-31'
     order by 
         card_No
)
select * from y;
```

Error message:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Clearly, you cannot.  I think the error message pretty much answers your question.

Comment: No you can't unless you specify `TOP`. Why do you want to sort a CTE?

Comment: What is the problem, they clearly said "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
". You cant use there

Comment: The error message already told you no, *and* told you what changes you could make that would allow it. If you've got a question, it's *unclear* what you're asking that isn't covered by the error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use "Order By" in a CTE but you can move the order by to the select statement calling the CTE and have the affect I believe you are looking for

```
;with y as(
select txn_Date_Time,txn_time,card_No,batch_No,terminal_ID
from C1_Transaction_Information
where txn_Date_Time='2017-10-31'

)

select * from y order by card_No;
```

Answer (score 10):

A good alternative is to use ROW_NUMBER inside the CTE:

```
;with y as
(
     select  
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY card_No),
         txn_Date_Time, 
         txn_time, 
         card_No, 
         batch_No, 
         terminal_ID
     from 
         C1_Transaction_Information
     where 
         txn_Date_Time = '2017-10-31'
)
select txn_Date_Time, 
         txn_time, 
         card_No, 
         batch_No, 
         terminal_ID
from y 
order by rn;
```

This gives you the option to then select TOP 10 as TOP ...ORDER BY is not allowed within a CTE:

```
;with y as
(
     select  
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY card_No),
         txn_Date_Time, 
         txn_time, 
         card_No, 
         batch_No, 
         terminal_ID
     from 
         C1_Transaction_Information
     where 
         txn_Date_Time = '2017-10-31'
)
select txn_Date_Time, 
         txn_time, 
         card_No, 
         batch_No, 
         terminal_ID
from y 
where rn <= 10;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thx!

Answer (score 4):

I needed to use the ORDER BY CLAUSE INSIDE the Common Table Expression. I was building up a SQL SELECT QUERY STATEMENT combining all the column names. I had to sort by the column `ORDINAL_POSITION`.

This is a way to force to use of the ORDER BY clause. After using the `ORDER BY` clause use `OFFSET 0 ROWS`.

```
WITH CTE_Example
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM A
ORDER BY [COL_A] ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Example
```

Comment: Wow! First time seeing this hack

Answer (score 1):

FYI
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

> The following clauses cannot be used in the CTE_query_definition:
>
> ORDER BY (except when a TOP clause is specified)
>
> INTO
>
> OPTION clause with query hints
>
> FOR BROWSE

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to actually use a order by inside a cte.

Method-1 (using offset)

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM A
    ORDER BY [mycol] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    )
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Method-2 (using TOP 100 percent)

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * 
    FROM A
    ORDER BY [mycol] ASC
    )
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY in a cte if the cte delivers JSON

```
WITH cte(n) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
), cte2(j) AS (
    SELECT n 
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY n
    FOR JSON PATH
)
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

[image]

The rationale is you can use ORDER BY in final output. Before final output, you can keep the columns necessary for the ordering to be called later.